# Create column that lists the hours between two timestamps with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Using SQL in Oracle -- I am needing to create a new column that lists the hours between two timestamps.. below is an example where "hour_list" is what needs to be created:

Table1:

```
    start                     finish                      hour_list
1/7/2024 4:57:00 AM    1/7/2024 1:29:00 PM        4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
1/7/2024 1:29:00 PM    1/7/2024 3:10:00 PM                13,14,15
1/8/2024 4:40:00 AM    1/8/2024 11:10:00 AM          4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Comment: Please note that this site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (start_time, end_time) as
  2    (select to_date('01.07.2024 04:57', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi'),
  3            to_date('01.07.2024 13:29', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  4     select to_date('01.07.2024 13:29', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi'),
  5            to_date('01.07.2024 15:10', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  6    )
```

Query aggregates hours between START and END times for each row in sample table:

```
  7  select start_time, end_time,
  8  listagg(to_char(start_time + (column_value - 1)  / 24 , 'hh24'), ', ')
  9      within group (order by column_value) as hour_list
 10  from test cross join
 11    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                        connect by level <= ceil((end_time - start_time) * 24) + 1
 13                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14  group by start_time, end_time;

START_TIME       END_TIME         HOUR_LIST
---------------- ---------------- ----------------------------------------
01.07.2024 04:57 01.07.2024 13:29 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13
01.07.2024 13:29 01.07.2024 15:10 13, 14, 15

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [recursive CTE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2).

```
with
  t("start", finish) as (
    select timestamp '2024-01-07 04:57:00',
           timestamp '2024-01-07 13:29:00' from dual union all
    select timestamp '2024-01-07 13:29:00',
           timestamp '2024-01-07 15:10:00' from dual union all
    select timestamp '2024-01-07 17:29:00',
           timestamp '2024-01-07 17:50:00' from dual
  ),
  r("start", finish, shour, hours) as (
    select
      t.*,
      extract(hour from "start"),
      cast(extract(hour from "start") as varchar2(80))
    from t
    union all
    select
      "start", finish,
      shour + 1,
      hours||','||to_char(shour + 1)
    from r
    where shour + 1 <= extract(hour from finish)
  )
select *
from r
where shour = extract(hour from finish);
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-------------------------+
|        start        |       FINISH        | SHOUR |          HOURS          |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-------------------------+
| 2024-01-07 17:29:00 | 2024-01-07 17:50:00 |    17 | 17                      |
| 2024-01-07 13:29:00 | 2024-01-07 15:10:00 |    15 | 13,14,15                |
| 2024-01-07 04:57:00 | 2024-01-07 13:29:00 |    13 | 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-------------------------+
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hk6ZLIQt).